# Docker context over SSH with different user

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

Is there any way to set up a docker context such that I can execute docker commands as another user on a remote box? I have a setup such that I ssh to a remote box as my own username, then interact once on that box with docker using a separate user which is in the docker group (with sudo -u userNameHere).

I'm hoping to be able to use docker contexts to deploy stuff on the box without having to SSH in directly, however it seems like this additional user step may make that impossible. Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck SSHing in for now?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `~/.ssh/config` so you always connect to some host(s) as a different user:

```
Host example.com *.example.com
    HostName example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    User admin
```

The above will make your ssh client to connect to `example.com` or any server that match `*.example.com` (server1.example.com for instance) as a user `admin`.

Comment: Would this not cause me to connect to the host as the user directly? My issue is that I don't know the user's password, only my own (and run commands on the other box as 'sudo -u username foo bar')

Comment: @Mithra oh, sorry, must have missed that. This of course will not help in your case. See this answer instead: https://superuser.com/questions/355029/how-to-automatically-run-commands-on-ssh-login